# How do I add a new application container to an existing rkt pod?

Tags: coreos, rkt

How do I add a new application container to an existing [rkt](https://coreos.com/rkt/) [pod](https://github.com/appc/spec/blob/master/spec/pods.md#app-container-pods-pods)?  The documentation for [`rkt run`](https://coreos.com/rkt/docs/latest/subcommands/run.html) shows how to launch multiple applications in a pod using a single command.  How might I achieve the same effect using multiple commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding apps to a running pod is currently not supported now. Previously, the pod is designed to be immutable for easy management. However as we see more and more use cases for it, we are now working on adding APIs for users to manipulate the pod in much lower level[1], e.g. inject/start/stop individual apps to the pod.

[1] expose application-level operations proposal: https://github.com/coreos/rkt/pull/2932